# How to obtain a path we are currently "on" the graph while knowing all graph nodes and weights?

Tags: python, networking, path-finding

I have a network composed of nodes and edges' weights. I know all of them. I get a "packet" which I know is travelling from `A` to `B` currently on node `C`. How to get minimal path it can be presently traversing (next and previous nodes)?

Comment: (a) "and rote prices." - do you mean route pricing (costs)? (b) Do you mean you have the costs of all the routes in the graph, from any node to any other node, whether they have an edge between them or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest path `A -> C -> B` must have the shortest `A->C` and `C->B` subpaths. It is trivial to prove. *Note*. The shortest path `A -> B` might not traverse `C`. Therefore the answer by @x00 might fail if you don't have apriory guarantee that `C` is selected correctly from the shortest path.

The previous node is the last segment on the path `A->C` and the next node is the first segment of the path `C->B`.

The shortest paths could be computed using Dijkstra algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Despite the claim in the accepted answer mine would work. Because

- If there is only one shortest path from `A` to `B`, then `C` **is** on the shortest path. The accepted answer itself clearly claims it with the phrases:

  > The shortest path `A -> C -> B` must have the shortest `A->C` and `C->B` subpaths.

  and

  > **It is trivial to prove**.
- So the only possibility for the `C` not to be on the shortest path is if there are several of them. The accepted answer doesn't address this issue **at all**. So it will give if not wrong but potentially misleading result. While here is clearly stated that

  > you need to find **all** shortest path**s**
- Which approach is simplest or fastest is totally another matter. Because performance will depend on specific implementation of a specific algorithm and on the net **topology**. It's not necessary true that finding one long path is slower than finding two smaller ones (without caching... and cache will add complexity).
- Anyway, checking the fact that there are several shortest paths is more general approach as it allows to make predictions on the implementation of the algorithm used to calculate the packet path.
- And if, by any chance, @PakUula meant that the shortest path between **three points** `A->C->B` is not necessary the same as the shortest path between **two points** `A->B` then his answer is incorrect. Exactly because path `A->C->B` is not the shortest between two points, and as a result `C` did not travel the shortest path, so we have no idea about the algorithm used to construct the path of the packet and/or our knowledge about net's weights is wrong. In that case see `theoretical exercise` and the end of this answer.

---

**The answer itself:**

I suppose we assume that packets always trying to follow the shortest path.

As a packet, before it starts it's journey from `A` to `B`, needs to know how to make it first move it already needs to know the shortest path. So you just find this shortest path between `A` and `B`, and after that you can find where is the `C` node on it.

Shortest path can be found with, for example, the Dijkstra’s algorithm, or some other. Them you can find on the internet with a request similar to "graph shortest path".

As you've said that edges' weights are known. Then there is nothing more to it. The `C` node will always be on the shortest path. <strike>Because there is only one shortest path</strike>... **Well actually - no**. There can be several paths with the same weight.

So you task is a little bit different - you need to find **all** shortest path**s**. And then you'll need to find which of then include `C` node. Again, there can be several paths with node `C`. So you can't answer your question with 100% certainty in these cases.

---

And just as a theoretical exercise: what if there is no `C` node on **any** of the shortest paths? That means that maybe there were some "obstacles" on the way and the plan had to be changed.

So what can be done about it?

It's quite easy to find the next node(s): just find the shortest path(s) between `C` and `B`. But still the answer won't always be definitive, because of the possibility of several routes of same weight.

But it becomes **impossible** to find the previous node without info about "obstacles". Because depending on them the packet can come from **any** direction. That essentially means that weights of the graph have changed and you don't know them.